# What is an "essential loop"?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm a bit confused. Is an essential loop in a topological space $X$ just a loop $\alpha$, which is not-contractible (i.e. $[\alpha] \neq 0$ in the fundamental group of $X$), or is there something more to it. Looking through the literature, I can't find a proper definition.

Thanks

Comment: That's the definition I know. Where did you see it first?

Comment: In Topology and Groupoids of Brown I find: 'A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is *inessential* if it is homotopic to a constant map—otherwise it is
*essential*. For example, any map to a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is inessential.'

Comment: It depends on the context, but that is the most common definition. Sometimes in the theory of surfaces a loop is said to be essential if it is not homotopic to a point and not homotopic into the neighborhood of a puncture.

Answer (score 1):

According to I. M. James in "History of Topology", page 575,

> > "An 'essential' map is one which is not homotopic to 0",

so your definition agrees with this one if the map is a loop.

But as Grumpy Parsnip said, it depends on the context.